# Sum of values ​in Django views

Tags: python, html, django

I intend to make a query to get a value and then add that value to 1 in the django views, but when I try to do that, I always get an error

```
def atualizar(request, contador):
        
        lista = factura.objects.filter(contador__contador=contador)
        conta1 = factura.objects.filter(contador__contador=contador).order_by('-contar')[:1]
        conta=conta1.values('contar') # this is value 
        cont=cliente.objects.filter(contador=contador).first() 
        if request.POST:
            
            data1=request.POST['data1']
            factura_nr=request.POST['factura_nr']
            data2=request.POST['data2']
            consumo=request.POST['consumo']
            
            dados = factura(
                contador=cont, 
                contar= conta +1, # to incremet here
                consumo=consumo,
                data1=data1,
                data2=data2,
                factura_nr=factura_nr

            )
            dados.save()
        
        return render(request, 'tabela.html', {'lista': lista,'cont':cont ,'conta':conta})[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdaMk.png)
```

Comment: Can you pleas share the models and explain *what* you want to sum up?

Comment: I want to get the value of this query ( count1 = invoice.objects.filter(contador__contador=contador).order_by('-count')[:1]
            count=count1.values('count') # this is the value ) and add it to a value here in view.py on (when post, save to the new value resulting from summing the value selected in the query with 1 => contar= conta + 1

Answer (score 1):

updated:
values() returns a Queryset that behaves similar to a dict. Simply try

```
=conta1['contar'] + 1
or
=conta[0]['contar']
```

to debug `print(conta)` and you will see it

please add the error trace in future posts

Comment: conta1 = factura.objects.filter(contador__contador=contador).order_by('-contar')[:1]
conta=conta1.values('contar')       I have only one value (conta) here in this selection and I intend to add this selected value with or integer value    eg: resl= conta+ 1

Comment: which error do you ger?

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QuerySet' and 'int'

Comment: see the update above

Comment: thank you very much it's functional

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the maximum `contar` and then increment this with one, like:

```
from django.db.models import Max


def atualizar(request, contador):
    lista = factura.objects.filter(contador__contador=contador)
    conta = lista.aggregate(max_contar=Max('contar'))['max_contar'] or 0
    cont = get_object_or_404(cliente, contador=contador)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data1 = request.POST['data1']
        factura_nr = request.POST['factura_nr']
        data2 = request.POST['data2']
        consumo = request.POST['consumo']
        dados = factura.objects.create(
            contador=cont,
            contar=conta + 1,  # to incremet here
            consumo=consumo,
            data1=data1,
            data2=data2,
            factura_nr=factura_nr,
        )
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')

    return render(
        request, 'tabela.html', {'lista': lista, 'cont': cont, 'conta': conta}
    )
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`factura`</s> to `Factura`.

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.